# JQuery CSS / Animate function failing on left absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

We have a JQuery function that controls a series of absolutely positioned panels that slide in and out from the left on top of each other. Originally this was controlled by webkit using JQuery `add/removeClass`. For greater compatibility we are now using JQuery with the ability to use webkit.

The problem is that the tab panels should start in `left:-560px;` The JQuery seams to ignore that in the CSS so I wrote in a line in the JQuery moving it there. It too has failed yet the actual function is working. The problem being that all the panels are starting at `left:0px;`

```
var tabbarpan;
        // THIS LINE SHOULD MOVE ALL PANELS TO left:-560px; BUT IT DOESN'T //
    $('#coursepack .corecol .chamber').css('left','-560');

    // NAVIGATION //
    $('#coursepack .tabbar a').click(function(){
        $('#coursepack .tabbar a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('#' + tabbarpan).animate({left:'-560', opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true},750);

        tabbarpan = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#' + tabbarpan).animate({left:'+0', opacity:1, leaveTransforms:true},750);

        $('#coursepack .review').removeClass('open');
        $('#coursepack .corecol .extention').animate({left:'=180px', opacity:0},{ duration: 500 });

        return false
    });
```

Any ideas why?

Marvellous

Comment: left:'=180px' , why "=" ? and px missed in lot of places ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#coursepack .corecol .chamber').css('left','-560');
```

You missed px in that line, should be

```
$('#coursepack .corecol .chamber').css('left','-560px');
```

Comment: and here too, ".animate({left:'-560'," - add px

Comment: Fascinating. Although that has worked now the 9th line does not. $('#' + tabbarpan).animate({left:'+0', opacity:1, leaveTransforms:true},750);

Comment: @Robin "leaveTransforms:true" , its not in basic jquery animate, I guess Its a part of plugin, you didn't mentioned it, make sure you linked and activated that plugin ...

Comment: It is the plugin. I just found it worked in old firefox were JQuery animate is used. In modern browsers its using CSS3 translate x,y and that is giving different results. Nearly fixed it and will put answer up in a minute

Answer (score 1):

you should use left with "px", like:-

```
.css('left','-560');
to
.css('left','-560px');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a result of the plugin used to enhance JQuery animate to use CSS3 wherever possible.

This plugin rather than using a transition on left, was usinging translate x,y. Thus on old browsers this was working perfectly and on modern ones not. A small rework of the code has fixed the problem forcing an animation first so that rather than moving the panel via CSS to begin with, we move it with animate, thus it will be translated for modern browsers by CSS3.

var tabbarpan;
    $('#coursepack .corecol .chamber').animate({left:'-560px', opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true},100);

```
// NAVIGATION //
$('#coursepack .tabbar a').click(function(){
    $('#coursepack .tabbar a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

 //ANIMATION FIRST FORCES TRANSLATE FOR CSS3 BROWSERS //
    $('#' + tabbarpan).animate({left:'-560px', opacity:0.6, leaveTransforms:true},750);

    tabbarpan = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#' + tabbarpan).animate({left:'+0px', opacity:1, leaveTransforms:true},750);

    $('#coursepack .review').removeClass('open');
    $('#coursepack .corecol .extention').animate({left:'=180px', opacity:0},{ duration: 500 });

    return false
});
```

Marvellous